# Rebinding [formGroup] does not work as expected

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form bound by `[formGroup]` and `[formControlName]`.

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="toggle"> CLICK ME</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>

export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // this.doIt();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doIt();
  }
  doIt() {
    const form = this.fb.group({
      toggle: this.form?.enable ?? true,
    });

    if (this.form?.enabled ?? false) {
      form.disable();
    }
    this.form = form;
  }
}
```

For whatever reasons when I rebuild `form` by calling `doIt()`, controls are not affected (`disabled` status of controls should change to reflect form state). Is that normal behavior?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c26bku?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you want form status to be `disabled` when the app starts.

You should  do the following. There is no need to create `const` for your form, you have that `form: FormGroup` property in the class itself. Working example should look like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    // this.doIt();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doIt();
  }
  doIt() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      toggle: this.form?.enabled ?? true,
    });

    if (this.form?.enabled ?? false) {
      console.log('enters if clause');
      this.form.disable();
    }
  }
}
```

The initial status of the form is `disabled` since it passes the `if` clause because `form` is enabled at the beginning.

Comment: Not when app starts, but when I recreate new form model. `doIt()` is attached as onclick event handler